# Javascript: Post data to PHP with fetch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm  using Ajax to submit data to PHP via POST method.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way serialize data instead of doing this

`const reqData = 'id= + ' myobj.id + '&name=' + myobj.name'`

Please note this ^ data is an object not form data.

2. How can I convert the ajax call to fetch

I have tried doing it like so. It returns 200 response code. but php didn't saved the data.

```
async function updateCountry(url, data) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    body: data,
  });
  return response;
}

updateCountry('some-url', data).then(resp => console.log(resp)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

here's my Ajax code:

```
const reqData = `id=${myobj.id}&name=${myobj.name}`;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'my-php-script-url',
  data: reqData,
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(typeof response);

    $('#saving-btn').hide();

    if (response.includes('success')) {
      $('#saved-btn').show();
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#saved-btn').hide();
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      $('#error-btn').show();
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#error-btn').hide();
      }, 3000);
    }
  },
  error: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  },
});
```

Comment: @AnanthSathvick haha... I have just added two fields here. but I have more than 30 fields. so I don't want to do it like :)

Comment: @AnanthSathvick That's wrong. It should be `data: {id: myobj.id, name: myobj.name}`. Don't put quotes around the parts of the object syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't support JSON parameters automatically, it requires the parameters to be either URL-encoded or FormData.

If the object keys are the same as the post parameters, you can write a loop to create the URL-encoded string:

```js
async function updateCountry(url, data) {
  const reqData = Object.entries(myobj).map(([key, value]) => key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)).join('&');
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },

    body: reqData,
  });
  return response;
}
```